# How to I install a 64-bit OS on my Ubuntu 64-bit with vm?

Tags: virtualbox

I have a copy of 64-bit 13.10 Ubuntu running on my x201. When I
open virtual box and click new, it doesn't show a 64-bit option for Windows 7. Running latest virtual box from virtualbox.org.

How can I fix this?

Thinkpad x201 laptop
Intel vpro i5 core

Comment: Can you provide more information on exactly what you downloaded (or what software source you enabled) from virtualbox.org? Also, do you know if your computer supports hardware virtualization? Most virtualization software these days, including VirtualBox, requires your 64-bit processor to have support for hardware virtualization technology in order to run 64-bit virtual machines: just having a 64-bit system and a 64-bit OS is usually *not* enough. Sometimes support for hardware virtualization has to be enabled in your computer's ("BIOS") setup utility. What CPU do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the answer myself. Just disable Intel TXT Feature. It works!!

Comment: How did you did it?

Comment: I just need to disable it in the BIOS configure section. Your BIOS may be different. But remember to keep 'vt-d' enabled

Answer (score 2):

Just choose the standard Windows 7 entry. If your host system is 64 bit, VirtualBox will always expose that to the guest, no matter what your settings are (see the [VirtualBox manual, Chapter 3. Configuring virtual machines](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have a computer with 64 bit processor and it supports hardware virtualization.

Then you should enable hardware vritualization through the BIOS setting. For details about setting BIOS, you can refer to [Want to install 64 bit OS on VirtualBox?](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1415440305-Want-to-install-64-bit-OS-on-VirtualBox)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same issue, with a windows 8.1 host. This was not an issue before the latest update to VirtualBox 4.3.8, the previous version 4.3.6 works fine. I recommend you down grade to that till a fix is released.

Older builds can be found [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3).

Comment: I think you just need to disable intel TXT feature

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Disabled Hardware Virtualizations  may cause the problem. check that option in your BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

BIOS Settings -> Advanced BIOS Setting -> Virtualization [Enabled] (was disabled) All 64bit platforms now show up in VirtualBox